# How to launch existing instance of an activity from static shortcut

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, android-appshortcut

I have an Activity(MainActivity) in my application and have one static shortcut(pointed to TempActivity).

As the static shortcuts will always have FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK set, I've created TempActivity which is an invisible Activity i.e It'll start MainActivity and then calls finish(). And also as suggested in developer docs SecondActivity has **android:taskAffinity=""** in the app's AndroidManifest.xml file.

MainActivity has android:launchMode="singleTop"

Even after doing this still MainActivity is getting launched in new task instead of existing task(created when launched from home screen).

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
                android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".TempActivity" android:taskAffinity=""></activity>
```

Shortcut

```
<shortcut
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:shortcutDisabledMessage="@string/app_name"
        android:shortcutId="static"
        android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/app_name"
        android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/app_name">
    <intent
        android:action="custom"
        android:targetClass="com.example.mobile.appshortcut.TempActivity"
        android:targetPackage="com.example.mobile.appshortcut" />
    </shortcut>
```

TempActivity.java

```
public class TempActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    //Intent intent = getIntent(); // From Shortcut
    Intent intent = new Intent(); // For Testing
    intent.setClass(this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
}
```

}

Link to developer docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ShortcutManager.html

Comment: Please give a minimal, complete example which illustrates what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Added some sample code. Hope this helps

Comment: you should include the actual class that has the onCreate() method.

Comment: What is the purpose of an activity that just launched another activity and quits?

Comment: It's the approach suggested in developer docs please go through the link I've mentioned

Comment: You showed the file name but not the class. Do you extend Activity or AppCompatActivity? If you just show `public class TempActivity extends ...` then this information is obvious. It might not be important to your question but it will make your code more complete.

Comment: I was referring to TempActiviy which seems useless.

Comment: I've added full class of TempActivity. TempActivity is the one which is launching MainActivity, it's not useless.

Comment: Why not launch MainActivity directly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137166/discussion-between-sankar-and-code-apprentice).

Comment: If I launch MainActivity directly then it's obvious that it'll get launched in new task

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`android:taskAffinity=""` should be on `MainActivity`, not `TempActivity`.

So your **AndroidManifest** should be something like that:

```
    <activity
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:taskAffinity=""
        android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
            android:resource="@xml/shortcut"/>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TempActivity"/>
```

And **TempActivity**

```
public class TempActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

}
```

And just to make sure, publishing my **shortcut.xml**

```
<shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <shortcut
        android:enabled="true"
        android:shortcutDisabledMessage="@string/app_name"
        android:shortcutId="compose"
        android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/app_name"
        android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/app_name">
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetClass="kidinov.org.test.TempActivity"
            android:targetPackage="kidinov.org.test"/>
        <categories android:name="android.shortcut.conversation"/>
    </shortcut>
</shortcuts>
```

I've created [sample project](https://github.com/kidinov/42633210_so_question) - it works fine. Feel free to check it out.

Comment: Thanks, It's working. I did try adding taskAffinity to MainActivity but I think here both SingleTask and taskAffinity combined doing the trick. But in developer docs it's mentioned that "The first activity should include an attribute setting of android:taskAffinity="" in the app's AndroidManifest.xml file, and the intent within the static shortcut should point at this first activity." If we look at this point taskAffinity should be there for the TempActivity, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Presumable you are using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` because you want a clean, new version of the activity when launched from this shortcut.

You can switch MainActivity launch mode to `singleInstance`. Then you have the option of using `onStart/onRestart` or `onNewIntent(Intent)` to clear down (and reset the activity and the TempActivity hack will no longer be required).

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    if (intent.getAction().equals("custom")) {
        //reset
    }
}
```