# Where should I add android:taskAffinity when I launch existing instance of an activity from static shortcut in Android Studio?

Tags: android

As the static shortcuts will always have `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` set,
I've created TempActivity which is an invisible Activity i.e It'll start MainActivity and then calls finish(). And also as suggested in developer docs SecondActivity has `android:taskAffinity=""` in the app's AndroidManifest.xml file.

I have read [Manage shortcuts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts/managing-shortcuts) and [How to launch an existing instance of activity from static shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42583078/how-to-launch-existing-instance-of-an-activity-from-static-shortcut/42633210#42633210).

You can see Image A and Image B. There are different opinions.

Where should I add android:taskAffinity when I launch an existing instance of activity from the static shortcut in Android Studio? MainActivity or TempActivity?

**Image A**

[image]

**Image B**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be on TrampolineActivity of course.
But the SO question you've provided has another error which makes it work eventually.
If you read the docs carefully, you can see the second bullet saying

> In the shortcuts resource file, the intent within the static shortcut should reference the trampoline activity

But the question from SO has wrongly set it on MainActivity's meta-data

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean that https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts/managing-shortcuts  is correct?

Comment: @HelloCW It definitely is